# NSPrintPanel, Go to the folder is not invoked on pressing '/' (mountain lion)

Tags: cocoa, pdf, printing

When I call the following code

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
[[NSPrintPanel printPanel] runModalWithPrintInfo:printInfo];
```

Click PDF->Save As PDF...
Delete the text and type '/' in name field

Per the Mac OS behavior 'Go to the Folder' should be invoked.

This works fine in Lion but doesn't in Mountain Lion

Do not want to go with `beginSheetWithPrintInfo` ?